# Какой смысл функции QThreadPool::setExpiryTimeout?

Tags: многопоточность, qt

ведь если я создаю Runnable где в run() бесконечный цикл, то через заданное время ведь поток НЕ будет прерван!

Код:

main

```
QThreadPool* pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance ();
pool->setExpiryTimeout(1000);
    Zayac* z = new Zayac;
    z->i = 0;
    z->ran =false;
    z->setAutoDelete(true);
    pool->start(z);
```

Runnable

```
class Zayac : public QRunnable
{
public:
    virtual void run ()
    {
        if(ran)
            return;
        ran=true;
        cout<<i<<") run\n";
        while(1)
        {
            cout<<i<<") running...\n";
        }
    }

    int i;
    bool ran;

};
```

В чем ее смысл тогда? А если мне нужна функции, которая должна прерываться, если "застряла" из-за внешних причин (например при записи в базу), то как это реализовать тогда (неужели руками?)?

```
//Кстати это тоже не помогает
pool->waitForDone(1000);
```

Пишут: Threads that are unused for a certain amount of time will expire
что вообще означает это "unused"? По каким критериям определяется used это или unused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял, поток уничтожается по истечении времени, если к нему не обращаются какими-либо функциями (например ThreadPool через новые вызовы run может "продлевать" жизнь созданного им потока) **ПОСЛЕ ЗАВЕРШЕНИЯ функции потока**. Таким образом бесконечный цикл просто не дает функции потока завершится и пул еще не начинает отсчет времени. Единственный способ избавится от "застравшего" (на вечно или на недопустимое время) потока это его аварийное завершение (терминация) через время, подсчитанное внешним ассинхронным счетчиком. А лучше не допускать возможности такого застревания в функции потока.